# Eternity Puzzle Decoded

Tags: reference-request

The story is about 13 years ago, when i was 17 and i remember that it was about solving the Eternity puzzle that I've seen in a newspaper.. in those days did not have a computer and I remember passing working all day and then going to the only net-cafe open 24/7 in my town looking information.. after three days tired of search it I've given up on finding no information, I thought it was just a lie, because the prize was $ 1M.

Well today i remember about this story and i search it on google., and i find [something](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/pound1m-for-man-who-solved-eternal-puzzle-634459.html) that give me the hope to search again about the story that got me into an adventure to no sleep almost three days many years ago :))

The sad thing is that I find just a one relatead link in whole internet.. so I would like if we can together figure out the whole story about this issue.

Edit: I do not remember very well the issue of the problem, because of course I would like to find it and see it all together.

Comment: Related site: http://www.mathpuzzle.com/eternity.html  But I can't quite tell what you are trying to ask in this question.

Comment: I try to ask about the info of the problem and his solution, right now i see the link that you sent, thank you so much!., you find it so quickly!!

Comment: this is so amazing Willie.. i find all the info in that link! thank you again.